# How to edit lines of all text files in a directory with python

Tags: python, text-files, ioerror

I would like to edit and replace lines of all .txt files in a directory with python for this purpose I am using the following code:

```
path = '.../dbfiles'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith(".txt"): 
        with open(i, 'r') as f_in:
            for line in f_in:
               line=tweet_to_words(line).encode('utf-8')  
               open(i, 'w').write(line)
```

where **`tweet_to_words(line)`** is a predefined function for edition lines of the text file.
Although I am not sure if the logic of the code is right!? I am also facing the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'thirdweek.txt'

but the **'thirdweek.txt'** exist in the directory!
So my question is to see if the method I am using for editing lines in a file is right or not!? and if so how can I fix the error ?

Comment: If the files are not huge (over 1MB), I suggest to first read the file with content = f.readlines(), then apply tweet_to_words to each element. After that open the file again for writing and write back the transformed lines (f.write("".join(content)))

Comment: You need to supply the proper path, as shown in Ohad's answer. And you need different logic to edit the file. Currently your `.write` call will wipe out all existing contents of the file. Either do what traianus suggests, or even simpler, create a new file containing the edited data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the base path when you use `open`:

```
        with open(path + '/' + i, 'r') as f_in:
```

the same goes for:

```
               open(path + '/' + i, 'w').write(line)
```

Comment: Although sting concatenation works, it's safer (&  more portable) to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Answer (score 1):

The glob module is useful for getting files with similar endings:

```
import glob

print glob.glob("*.txt")  # Returns a list of all .txt files, with path info

for item in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    temp = []  # Might be useful to use a temp list before overwriting your file
    with open(item, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print line  # Do something useful here
            temp.append(line)
    with open(item, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(temp)
```